# ES6: Save variable into module scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to know if and how it's possible to save the following `config` into my modules scope (think of the block below as one module):

```
var config = null;

var mySingleton = {
    init: function(config) {
        config = config; // Naming conflict!
    },

    printConfig: function() {
        console.log(config); // Undefined!
    }
};

export { mySingleton };
```

Unfortunately, a naming conflict occurs. I'd need something like `module.config = config;`.

Note: I'm using the [es6-module-transpiler](http://square.github.io/es6-module-transpiler/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's a simple variable, and not a global one (where it would be accessible as a property of the global object), so it just is shadowed and not available "namespaced".

You need to use a different name to resolve conflicts, which should be trivial and will cause no effects outside the module:

```
var config = null;

var mySingleton = {
    init: function(conf) {
        config = conf;
    },
    printConfig: function() {
        console.log(config);
    }
};

export { mySingleton };
```

Comment: Another thought, tell me what you think: `var module = {};`, and then: `init: function (config) { module.config = config }`, creating an own module namespace may be a bit nicer than renaming the variable?

Comment: It would work, but looks cumbersome. I don't understand why you haven chosen the same variable name in the first place…